# Is there any way to avoid LEFT JOIN the same table

Tags: mysql

There are two tables i.e user and attribute.

user table-

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   user_id |   u_at1   |   u_at2   |   u_at3   |   u_at4   |   u_atN   |   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |    3      |     4     |   6       |   100     |   Null    |   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2       |    Null   |     623   |   Null    |   85      |    1      |   
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

attribute table

```
-----------------------
|   at_id   |   at_text |
 -----------------------
|    1      |    at1    |
 -----------------------
|    2      |    at2    |
 -----------------------
|    3      |    at3    |
 -----------------------
|    4      |    at4    |
 -----------------------
|    5      |    at5    |
 -----------------------
|    6      |    at6    |
 -----------------------
|    85     |    at85   |
 -----------------------
|    100    |    at100  |
 -----------------------
|    500    |    at500  |
 -----------------------
|    623    |    at623  |
 -----------------------
```

Attribute table store attribute id and attribute text. In the user table, the user attribute column (for example u_at3) store the attribute id. In the user table, u_atN column is for example purpose i.e the attribute column count can be u_at20. Thats why I did not include all column here.

Now my question is this ok if I make LEFT JOIN 20 times for the same table or is there any other method I can do this? Here is my query-

```
 SELECT 
    `user`.*,
    `attribute1`.`at_text`,
    `attribute2`.`at_text`
    `attribute3`.`at_text`
    `attribute4`.`at_text`
    .....................
    .....................
    `attribute20`.`at_text`
    
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `attribute` `attribute1` ON `user`.`u_at1` = `attribute1`.`at_id`,
LEFT JOIN `attribute` `attribute2` ON `user`.`u_at2` = `attribute2`.`at_id`,
LEFT JOIN `attribute` `attribute3` ON `user`.`u_at3` = `attribute3`.`at_id`,
LEFT JOIN `attribute` `attribute4` ON `user`.`u_at4` = `attribute4`.`at_id`,
...................................................................
...................................................................
JOIN `attribute` `attribute20` ON `user`.`u_at20` = `attribute20`.`at_id`,
WHERE `user_id` = 2;
```

Comment: Normalise your schema

Answer (score 1):

When using MySQL aggregation you can use MAX() aggregation function on strings so you can do a full join and use an if statement to use the value of the attribute or null for each field depending on the id matching. Then aggregate by user_id!

Example.

```
SELECT `user_id`,
  MAX(IF(`attribute`.`at_id`=`user`.`u_at1`,`attribute`.`at_text`,NULL)) as `u_at1_value`,
  MAX(IF(`attribute`.`at_id`=`user`.`u_at2`,`attribute`.`at_text`,NULL)) as `u_at2_value`, 
  MAX(IF(`attribute`.`at_id`=`user`.`u_at3`,`attribute`.`at_text`,NULL)) as `u_at3_value`,
  MAX(IF(`attribute`.`at_id`=`user`.`u_at4`,`attribute`.`at_text`,NULL)) as `u_at4_value`
FROM `user`,`attribute` 
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Performance wise I think its faster to use subqueries for each field though, due to the MySQL optimizer.

```
SELECT `user_id`,
  (SELECT `at_text` FROM `attribute` WHERE `user`.`u_at1` = `attribute`.`at_id`) as `u_at1_value`,
  (SELECT `at_text` FROM `attribute` WHERE `user`.`u_at2` = `attribute`.`at_id`) as `u_at2_value`,
  (SELECT `at_text` FROM `attribute` WHERE `user`.`u_at3` = `attribute`.`at_id`) as `u_at3_value`,
  (SELECT `at_text` FROM `attribute` WHERE `user`.`u_at4` = `attribute`.`at_id`) as `u_at4_value`
FROM `user`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good approach. You may get a lot of duplicate results if attribute_ids are the same for different ids. Moreover, 20 left joins on RDBMS will make your DB crusted and is an unrealistic approach.
To resolve your problem, you can redesign the DB.

```
user table:
user_id
attribute_id
```

And

```
Attribute table:
    attribute_id,
    text1_column
    text2_column
    text3_column
    ....
    .....
    text20_column
```

Then, you just do a single join, pick data from your database. Process and in which column you find data, use that according to your need.
I am not saying this is the best solution but at least, this will decrease your complexity in a drastical way.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The duplicate result can be avoided by adding a column alias. But my main concern is for performance for 20 left join.

Comment: you are right about the duplicate results. And for performance, there is a huge possibility that your application will stuck and db will remain locked for a long time which is not desired. For each left join, the complexity increases like this MxN1xN2x....N20 which I assume you don't want in your system at all!